# Symfony - mysql column sum

Tags: php, mysql, database

I wrote mysql query that needs to collect the SUM of amount field by selected user(in this table, user_id foreign key to Users table).

It look like this and it works..

> SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_sum, user_id FROM user_donation
>     Group by user_id

I have trouble writing it in symfony to do the exact same thing. I can't figure out what am I doing wrong..

My code..

```
 public function getTotalDonated($userId)
{
    $user = $this->getUserRepository()->find($userId);

    $query = $this->getDonationRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('g')
        ->select("SUM(amount) AS total_sum, user")
        ->groupBy('g.user')
        ->setParameter(['user' => $user])
        ->getQuery();

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: It can't define (find) specified user_id...

Comment: Just need to correctly write quoted part as query.. SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_sum, user_id FROM user_donation Group by user_id

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->getDonationRepository()
        ->createQueryBuilder('g')
        ->select("SUM(g.amount) AS total_sum")
        ->where('g.user = :user')
        ->groupBy('g.user')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $query;
```

I found the solution!